# PHP: How do I linkify all links inside a given text?

Tags: php

I am using the tool https://github.com/jmrware/LinkifyURL to detect URLs in a text unit. Unfortunately, it only recognizes **one** URL in the whole text. For example, if the text ought to be:

> http://www.guiageo-americas.com/imagens/imagem-america-do-sul.jpg I
>   really think this should be working
>   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cy8duEIHEig more text and some writing
>   here and there

what appears is:

> **http://www.guiageo-americas.com/imagens/imagem-america-do-sul.jpg** I
>   really think this should be working
>   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cy8duEIHEig more text and some writing
>   here and there

and what I want is:

> **http://www.guiageo-americas.com/imagens/imagem-america-do-sul.jpg** I
>   really think this should be working
>   **http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cy8duEIHEig** more text and some writing
>   here and there

Any idea on why? Of course, I'll leave the PHP code here:

```
function linkify($text) {

 /* $text being "http://www.guiageo-americas.com/imagens/imagem-america-do-sul.jpg I really think this should be working http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cy8duEIHEig more text and some writing here and there" */

    $url_pattern = '/# Rev:20100913_0900 github.com\/jmrware\/LinkifyURL
    # Match http & ftp URL that is not already linkified.
      # Alternative 1: URL delimited by (parentheses).
      (\()                     # $1  "(" start delimiter.
      ((?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9\-._~!$&\'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]+)  # $2: URL.
      (\))                     # $3: ")" end delimiter.
    | # Alternative 2: URL delimited by [square brackets].
      (\[)                     # $4: "[" start delimiter.
      ((?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9\-._~!$&\'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]+)  # $5: URL.
      (\])                     # $6: "]" end delimiter.
    | # Alternative 3: URL delimited by {curly braces}.
      (\{)                     # $7: "{" start delimiter.
      ((?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9\-._~!$&\'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]+)  # $8: URL.
      (\})                     # $9: "}" end delimiter.
    | # Alternative 4: URL delimited by <angle brackets>.
      (<|&(?:lt|\#60|\#x3c);)  # $10: "<" start delimiter (or HTML entity).
      ((?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9\-._~!$&\'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]+)  # $11: URL.
      (>|&(?:gt|\#62|\#x3e);)  # $12: ">" end delimiter (or HTML entity).
    | # Alternative 5: URL not delimited by (), [], {} or <>.
      (                        # $13: Prefix proving URL not already linked.
        (?: ^                  # Can be a beginning of line or string, or
        | [^=\s\'"\]]          # a non-"=", non-quote, non-"]", followed by
        ) \s*[\'"]?            # optional whitespace and optional quote;
      | [^=\s]\s+              # or... a non-equals sign followed by whitespace.
      )                        # End $13. Non-prelinkified-proof prefix.
      ( \b                     # $14: Other non-delimited URL.
        (?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/      # Required literal http, https, ftp or ftps prefix.
        [a-z0-9\-._~!$\'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]+ # All URI chars except "&" (normal*).
        (?:                    # Either on a "&" or at the end of URI.
          (?!                  # Allow a "&" char only if not start of an...
            &(?:gt|\#0*62|\#x0*3e);                  # HTML ">" entity, or
          | &(?:amp|apos|quot|\#0*3[49]|\#x0*2[27]); # a [&\'"] entity if
            [.!&\',:?;]?        # followed by optional punctuation then
            (?:[^a-z0-9\-._~!$&\'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]|$)  # a non-URI char or EOS.
          ) &                  # If neg-assertion true, match "&" (special).
          [a-z0-9\-._~!$\'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]* # More non-& URI chars (normal*).
        )*                     # Unroll-the-loop (special normal*)*.
        [a-z0-9\-_~$()*+=\/#[\]@%]  # Last char can\'t be [.!&\',;:?]
      )                        # End $14. Other non-delimited URL.
    /imx';

       //below goes my code

    $url_replace = '$1$4$7$10$13<a style="color:blue;" onclick="toogleIframe(this)">$2$5$8$11$14</a>$3$6$9$12';
    //echo preg_replace($url_pattern, $url_replace, $text);
    return preg_replace($url_pattern, $url_replace, $text);
}
```

Comment: @JakeGould It is indeed! I don't actually know the guy (Jeff Roberson) but he certainly is good at it :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the kind of thing best left to a 3rd party library (which you're doing, so kudos). I'd recommend trying another one before you roll your own. [purl](https://github.com/jwage/purl) is an excellent alternative.

Comment: Ty for your tip, but can't you actually think of a workaround using this one? It's kind of what I really wanted because this is almost functioning to perfection, I don't feel like risking it with another module :p

Comment: Almost working to perfection and actually working are often miles apart. My recommendation stands: find a different library that actually works. This might be a good time to look into http://getcomposer.org. Swapping out libraries is a cinch with Composer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to replace all matches of your regex (though, I won't count on its performance):

```
while (preg_match($pattern, $string)) {
    $string = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
}
```

So, your function will become:

```
function linkify($text) {
    $url_pattern = "<your-pattern-string">;
    $url_replace = "<your-replacement-string">;
    while (preg_match($url_pattern, $url_replace, $text) {
        $text = preg_replace($url_pattern, $url_replace, $text);
    }
    return $text;
}
```